# AudioContext Warning upon trying to play an audio while using WaveSurfer.js

Tags: javascript, html, audiocontext, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to play an audio and generating it's waveform using Wavesurfer.js, however when I click the `Play` button, an `AudioContext` warning gets displayed in the console and the audio does not play. This issue is weird in a way, because it does not happen all the time but seems to occur randomly.

Code (HTML):

```
<button type="button" id="btn-playpause" title="Play or pause the audio.">
<img src="playpause.svg" alt="SVG image" width="25px" height="25px">
</button>
```

Code (Javascript):

```
const playButton = document.getElementById("btn-playpause");
playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wavesurfer.playPause();
    console.log("Clicked Play/Pause");
})
```

I have also tried this, it gives the same error:

```
const playButton = document.getElementById("btn-playpause");
playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("Clicked Play/Pause");
    if (wavesurfer.isPlaying()){
        wavesurfer.pause();
    }
    else{
        wavesurfer.play();
    }
})
```

[The error in console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7OCM.png)

Please do let me know some fixes if possible, thanks.